# Servlet: Alternative to SimpleFileServlet

Tags: java, servlets

I have to make a Servlet for the static resources. Actually i'am using the IBMs SimpleFileServlet but i need an alternative for WAS8 version.

¿Any idea? Thanks for all.

Comment: Not related to your question but using WebServer to serve static resources will be much faster

Comment: Thanks but must be a Servlet.